# How to return specific word from a column in r from a list of text in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text, filter

I have a dataframe of two variables. lets say my data frame is df, then the two variables are df$id , df$address. df$address contains full address, like  TT Road, Bhopal, Madhya Pradesh 462003. I have another data frame contain 10 places and one among the 10 is bhopal. so I want to return only bhopal in a new column. this is an example I have more than 200000 ids and 300 place name.
below is the example

data frame 1 :

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("297308272","297308281","297308299"), address = c("MGROAD, AMBIKAPUR, CH-546453","TT Road, Bhopal, Madhya Pradesh 462003","STREET NO. 2, WHITEFIELD, PALI, RJ"))
```

data frame 2:

```
 AD <- data.frame(place = c("Bhopal", "Pali", "Wardha", "AMBIKAPUR", "Anuhul"))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Post an expected output from `df` and `AD` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by first converting the entire address column of the data.frame and the place vector to lower case.

```
df$address<-tolower(df$address)

#> df
#    id                                address
#1 297308272           mgroad, ambikapur, ch-546453
#2 297308281 tt road, bhopal, madhya pradesh 462003

place<-tolower(place)

#> place
# "bhopal"    "pali"      "wardha"    "ambikapur"
# [5] "anuhul"
```

Now let's split the string into words using " " as the separator. For this we will use the `strsplit` in R.

```
listofstrvec<-strsplit(x = df$address,split = " ")

#> listofstrvec
# [[1]]
# [1] "mgroad,"    "ambikapur," "ch-546453" 

# [[2]]
# [1] "tt"      "road,"   "bhopal," "madhya"  "pradesh"
# [6] "462003"
```

Now we have a list of vectors of strings. Now we will try to clean these strings a little bit more. We will use the `gsub` function in R to remove the unwanted punctuation. This step you might have to try a few combinations depending upon how dirty your data is.

```
listofstrvec<-lapply(listofstrvec,FUN = gsub,pattern="[\\,\\.\\-]",replacement= "")

#> listofstrvec
# [[1]]
# [1] "mgroad"    "ambikapur" "ch546453" 

# [[2]]
# [1] "tt"      "road"    "bhopal"  "madhya"  "pradesh"
# [6] "462003"
```

Now we will try to `match` the locations in places with each of the strings in the vectors.

```
matched.place<-lapply(X = listofcharvec,FUN = match,table=place)
#> matched.place
#[[1]]
#[1] NA  4 NA

#[[2]]
#[1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA
```

Finally, using the combination of `sapply`, `is.na` and `length` function you can get the locations in a vector.

```
df$place<-sapply(matched.place,function(t){ifelse(test = (length(!is.na(t))>0),
yes = place[t[!is.na(t)]],no = NA)})

#> df
#         id                                address     place
#1 297308272           mgroad, ambikapur, ch-546453 ambikapur
#2 297308281 tt road, bhopal, madhya pradesh 462003    bhopal
```

Comment: @Subhashree if it worked for you would you please accept this answer or is there something that did not work for you.